# Translate odata URi string to HIbernate for MYSQL database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, odata

Is there an easy way, via a Java library or something to translate an Odata URI string into SQL, HQL or Hibernate Criteria for use with a MYSQL database? We are using Infragistics igGrid and the 'Remote Filtering' feature sends a URI parm string like this back to my servlet :

```
&$filter=indexof(tolower(number),'1')+ge+0+and+tolower(name)+eq+'Project1'+and+tolower(status)+eq+'new'
```

I was told this is an 'Odata' type query... but what do I do with it? I 'simply' want to translate this into SQL, HQL or Hibernate Criteria objects so I can query my database. I've seen some mention of Olingo, odata4j, REST, PHP, LINQ, creating an Odata MySQL server... I don't think I want any of that, I just want to translate this odata string into SQL.

Does anyone know if it can be done? Or should I be attacking this in another way? Thanks for any tips.